# How to add a computed property with underscore js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

We need to add an additional property to an object array.

The array:

```
var data = [
    {
        event:'event 1',
        status:'Upcoming'
    }
    {
        event:'event 2',
        status:'Completed'
    }
    {
        event:'event 3',
        status:'Canceled'
    }
    ...
]
```

To give the status label a different color based on its value, we want to convert the array into something like:

```
var result = [
    {
        event:'event 1',
        status:'Upcoming',
        statusCss:'label-success'
    }
    {
        event:'event 2',
        status:'Completed',
        statusCss:'label-info'
    }
    {
        event:'event 3',
        status:'Canceled',
        statusCss:'label-warning'
    }
    ...
]
```

It is easy to come up with a JavaScript `for` loop to do it:

```
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var t = data[i];
                    if (t.status === 'Upcoming') t.statusCss = "label-success";
                    if (t.status === 'Canceled') t.statusCss = "label-warning";
                    if (t.status === 'Completed') t.statusCss = "label-info";
                    result.push(t);
                }
```

But, is there anything in underscore.js that can handle this transformation with less code?

Comment: Anyway, you can always look at [the doc](http://underscorejs.org)

Comment: Are you simply looking for [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)? There is no helper method that allows you to set a property based on another property's value.

Comment: @FelixKling: Actually, he is *modifying* each object in the array, so there's no real reason to create a new `result` object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You could use map. Map iterates over a collection and allows you to modify items in the collection and return these to a new collection.

```
data = _.map(data, function(val) {
  if (val.status === 'Upcoming') val.statusCss = "label-success";
  if (val.status === 'Canceled') val.statusCss = "label-warning";
  if (val.status === 'Completed') val.statusCss = "label-info";
  return val;
});
```

This will go ahead and modify data so that data contains the same list of objects that you had before, but with the new properties